# What's the teacher's fractional addition algorithm?

Tags: mathematics

One day my tenth-grade math teacher walked into our classroom and said, "Class, today to start off the class I've got an addition problem for you. Give me any two positive proper fractions and I'll add them up."

Some of us were a bit bewildered at that, but one of the students decided to bite. "1/2 plus 1/2", he said.

"11/20", answered our teacher.

We were a bit surprised. "Shouldn't that be 1, teacher?"
"Nope," he said. "I'm not using your standard addition algorithm today."

"Alright, what about 1/3 + 2/3"?

"That's 4/11", said the teacher.

"How about 2/9 + 7/9?"

"That's 3/11."

The teacher wrote our questions and his answers on the board along with a few more:

```
1/2 + 1/2 = 11/20
1/3 + 2/3 = 4/11
2/9 + 7/9 = 3/11
3/20 + 4/20 = 1/8
1/9 + 1/9 = 1/9
1/30 + 5/6 = 1/12
```

Can you figure out what addition algorithm the teacher was using?

Comment: If you want the results of any more additions, just ask.

Comment: How much is 11/13 + 11/13?

Comment: I want to know some points about your representation system (which your question currently does not mention) : Is AB/AC=B/C ? Is A+B=B+A ? If A+B1=C & A+B2=C, then is B1=B2 ? Is (A+B)+C=A+(B+C) ? Is RightHandSide the "exact output" or simplified by removing common factors ?

Comment: @JoeZ. [unrelated] I took the liberty of decoding your display picture's GB values to ascii characters as I have been wondering about it. This is what I got: "∙►☻ tπZ╫@U─cVê┐" ...very interesting secret.

Comment: @MarkN: It's no secret. That's just the infamous [AACS 09F9 key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AACS_encryption_key_controversy).

Comment: @JoeZ. I see..also I was mistaken, it translates to "∙◄☻¥tπ[╪AV┼cVê└" (for those that read hex as ascii.)

Comment: @leoll2 Since this seemed to still be open, I'll answer for Joe: 11/13 + 11/13 = 884467/1000001

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rule:

> Write both numbers on the left side as decimal, create the resulting number by picking digits in alternating order.

Calculations:

> Left first, right second:
>
>  1) 0.5 + 0.5 = 0.55
>  2) 0.3333 + 0.6666 = 0.36363636
>  3) 0.2222 + 0.7777 = 0.27272727
>  4) 0.15 + 0.2 = 0.125
>  5) 0.1111 + 0.1111 = 0.11111111
>  6) 0.0333 + 0.8333 = 0.08333333

Comment: This is the same answer I came up with, didn't notice tho that 4 and 7 were inversed so I thought it wasn't the right answer :P

Comment: It seems like the simpler fraction out of left and right was chosen in each case, which might explain the discrepancy of 4 and 7.

Comment: Looking over it again, number 7 doesn't quite match. Keep on looking, there might still be a better answer that correctly explains it all. Then again, I can't seem to get the numbers typed correctly myself, even after two edits, so maybe the author fell for the same trap. :-)

Comment: The additional rule could be the even vs. odd digit after the decimal point.

Comment: No, 2 and 3 contradict that, one starts odd, the other even. I also tried lower digit goes first, doesn't work for 7 though.

Comment: +1 , I think there is no need for looking further. Discrepancies must be due **typos by OP**. It is unlikely that some other algorithm can get the same output.

Comment: Yep, it's supposed to be left first. if something's wrong there, I made typos. Sorry :S